# How to prevent SQL injection when using sequence.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL?

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I have an SQL query taking in a column name from backend.

```
SELECT ${sequenceName}.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
```

I am doing this in MyBatis, and while usually I'd stick to #{} instead of ${}, in this case i need the string concatanation, so I am unable to prevent SQL injection this way. Is there a solution or method where SQL injection does not occur when I am doing dynamic queries and string substitution for SQL?

Perhaps something like:

```
SELECT (Select SEQUENCE_NAME from ALL_SEQUENCES where SEQUENCE_NAME = ?).NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
```

?

Comment: Why you SQL query isn't working for you?

Comment: the SQL works, but I just want to get a statement that does not have SQL injection vulnerabilities

Comment: Your example (second) is not vulnerable to SQL injections